# C# times matching

Tags: c#, date, time, string-matching

I have written a small function in C# which isn't my main launguage so is coming across a little foreign to me.

```
public bool CheckForKey(string key)
{
    string strKeyTime = Decode(key);
    //valid key will be current time +- 5 minutes
    string strTheTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");

    if (strKeyTime == strTheTime)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need to alter this to allow for 5 minutes, so 
    if (strKeyTime == strTheTime)
needs to be
    if (strKeyTime == strTheTime + or - 5 minutes)

my problem is matching the times as they are strings, perhaps convert key(original time) back to a date first and then do it, but I am pretty new to c#

Comment: `return strKeyTime == strTheTime;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert (or keep) them both to DateTimes you can use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.TIMESPAN%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

```
TimeSpan delta = dateTime1 - dateTime2;
if (Math.Abs(delta.TotalMinutes) <= 5) { ... }
```

Look into using the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) (or any of the Parse... methods) to parse your strKeyTime, and then do something similar to the above.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your sent string to the equivalent DateTime value, use the following code:

```
var keyDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strKeyTime);
var strTheTime = DateTime.Now
```

from here, you can use this value to compare with your original time value as the following:

```
if (keyDateTime == strTheTime || (keyDateTime > strTheTime && keyDateTime < strTheTime.AddMinutes(5))
{
    return true;
}
```

the previous block of code will first check if we got an exact match, or the time sent to the method is between the original time and a time shift of additional 5 minutes.

that's it, if this is not what you need, let me know so I may update my answer for you, thanks.

-- if my answer is correct, don't forget to "Mark as answer".

Answer (score 0):

"perhaps convert key(original time) back to a date first and then do it" sounds like a sound solution. I'd do it this way:

- Convert both strings to DateTime instances.
- Store difference in TimeSpan instance using `DateTime.Subtract(DateTime value)` ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx )
- Check if TimeSpanInstance.TotalMinutes is less than or equal to 5.

The first step is something I can't really give you any advice on without information concerning how your string is formatted. However, once this is done, the rest should be easy.